# How to display files generated to build space in QtCreator

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

I use a `CMakeLists.txt` like the following

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(generate_files_from_tool)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT generated_config.cpp
    COMMAND bash ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/writeSourceFileFromConfigXml.sh ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.xml > ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated_config.cpp
    DEPENDS config.xml writeSourceFileFromConfigXml.sh
    )

add_executable(tool_with_generated_file main.cpp generated_config.cpp)
```

which generates a file (here `generated-config.cpp`) in the build process using a custom script (`writeSourceFileFromConfigXml.sh`).
I can open it using QtCreator 4.4.1 just fine: Compile and run works -- but I cannot see the file `generated_config.cpp` in the *Projects* view, only `CMakeLists.txt` and `main.cpp` is visible there.
If I open the file "manually", QtCreator displays a warning "This file is not part of any project." -- but it *uses* the file for the compilation.  And after opening the file, I'm able to switch between definition and implementation using *Ctrl+Klick* or *F2* (and get to/come from `generated_config.cpp`)

So my question is: How can I make QtCreator understand, that this generated file is part of the project and add it to the *Projects* view?

Note: changing the last line to `add_executable(tool_with_generated_file main.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated_config.cpp)` did not change anything.

Comment: If I add `file(GLOB_RECURSE generatedCode "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/*.cpp")
add_custom_target(qtcreator_displa_fix SOURCES ${generatedCode})` to `CMakeLists.txt` I don't find the `generated-config.cpp`, but instead `CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp` deep in the cmake build folder.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The generated files show up correctly under `<Build Directory>` in the Projects view with Qt Creator 4.3.1 on my machine.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: I cannot see a `<Build Directory>` as well.  I'm running Linux -- maybe that matters?!?  Do you know of a setting to enable showing/hiding the `<Build Directory>`?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a workaround to show generated sources located outside of build directory:
I have symlinks created in PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR to directories where generated sources are located, say src1, src2 (it is important to not use real paths). Then I use :

```
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src1/*.[ch] ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src2/*.[ch])
add_custom_target(
    all_src
    SOURCES ${SOURCE_FILES}
)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.  It's a quite intrusive workaround, though (you need to change both the filesystem and your cmake code) -- most projects won't accept that "just" for making QtCreator show stuff.  But for some it might be helpful ;-)